# Add a number and a Text Input value with adobe flex

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, development-environment, flash-builder

I am trying to add a number and a text input value to display in a label. here is my code thus far.

```
  'lblAnswer.text = bloodglucose + 100;'
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: are you getting a crash or not compiling or what's the issue?

Comment: It keeps giving me my number with 100 at the end of it. For instance if I insert 3 into the bloodglucose text input , lblAnswer displays 3100

Comment: are you trying to display 103 in that case?

Comment: Yes , the Bloodglucose Input will be added with 100 . So BGL + 100 should = 103

Comment: Above you say "the bloodglucose input" -- which makes it sound like this value is coming from a text input or some other text based component. If that's the case `bloodglucose` is not really a number it's a string. And none of the answers below will help. If the latest answer doesn't help (and I don't think it will since the first answer didn't seem to help), you need to tell us where the value for `bloodglucose` is coming from: is it a numerical value that you've deinfed in code, or it is a number that the user of your app types into a text input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following answer -

```
bloodglucose += 100;
lblAnswer.text = String(bloodglucose);
```

Hope this will work :)

Answer (score 2):

Sunil is correct - when doing mixed type addition, the UI input first needs to be coerced to either int or Number. IE: Number(bloodglucose) + 100; This assumes bloodglucose is actually a getter to the input text reference. If it's not, then you need to coerce the property and not the id of the component.

```
Getter: public function get bloodglucose():Number { return Number(myInput.text); }
In method: lblAnswer.text = bloodglucose + 100;

or (bloodglucose is a UIComponent):
In method: lblAnswer.text = Number(bloodglucose.text) + 100;
```

Comment: Thank you Mike, I will try these steps, and I will be sure to provide an update.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `String(int i)`

```
lblAnswer.text = String(bloodglucose + 100);
```

**Update:** What about something like this:

```
var i:int = bloodglucose + 100;
var s:String = String(i);
lblAnswer.text = s;
```

Comment: This is the error I got when I tried that code  
1120: Access of undefined property Integer.

Comment: Still adds 100 to the end of what ever the value is. 50100, 19100. Instead of 150 and 119.

Comment: It used to work when I used a Slider instead of a Text Input. I used slider.value. But for some reason .value isn't available after a text Input

Comment: No Problem, I do appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

** Update ,

I am changing the code from the update that was previously posted. I initially found that because I was including the string value inside of the equation this is what was prompting an error. You have to wrap the converted components to Number inside of the string all together. Basically convert the components to a number, then convert the answer received into a string.

Below is an example of the wrong code.

```
txtAnswer = (String(Number(bloodglucose)+100)) / 36)).toFixed(2)
```

Below this line is the fixed code.

```
txtAnswer.text = String( (Number(bloodglucose.text) + (Number(100))/ (Number(36))).toFixed(2) ;
```

The .toFixed Property signifies how many decimal places I want the returned value to display.